# admin_enqueue_scripts the same css file as wp_enqueue_style

Tags: admin, css

I am using sass and grunt to merge and minify a number of scss files and using `wp_enqueue_style` to load the single minified css file which works fine. I have also merged the scss for the admin section, but I have been told this does not work unless using `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

I am trying to reduce the number of http requests the user has to make on first navigation to the site, so I would rather not split the files separately. If I use `admin_enqueue_scripts` to enqueue the *exact* same minified css file as `wp_enqueue_style`, is this a security risk?

Comment: This is probably better asked elsewhere. For example: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37832/css-based-attacks